# Cannot compile a dummy class using gradle

Tags: gradle, build

I am trying to use gradle for the first time and is not really working. I hope you can help.

My class is the following:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.apache.commons.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    org.joda.time.LocalTime currentTime = new org.joda.time.LocalTime();
    System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);
  }
}
```

This java class is stored in the folder source/java/

I have written the following build.gradle:

```
group 'alive'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.2'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '17.0'
}   

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'source/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'source/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

When I run "gradle build" I receives a compilation error. The package org.apache.commons cannot be found.

Comment: Also, why don't you simply respect the standard project layout? And why don't you use the shorter dependency notation: `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'`?

Comment: very interesting answers... for some other questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The star notation includes all classes in the given package. It doesn't include sub packages. The package itself contains no classes and that's why the compiler fails. In your program you don't use anything from commons, so you can freely delete the line. When you start using it, let the IDE take care of the imports for you. If you want to import something from the commons library yourself, do e.g.:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;
```

or

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
```

The reason why it works for the joda time is because you are referencing the class with full package name:

```
org.joda.time.LocalTime ...
```

That's why it doesn't need to be imported.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, but I think that you missed the point. As the title says, that class is a dummy class. It is used just to test the gradle build. I know that the package commons is not used and I can remove the import, but the point is that I do not know why gradle finds the joda classes but not the apache.commons package.

Comment: @JamesHenry that has nothing to do with gradle. javac throws this error because you're importing all classes from a package which doesn't contain any class.

Comment: @JamesHenry added a reason to the answer why the joda time worked